# What is wrong with my Bash script for automatic installation of devstack?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I created this bash script for an automatic installation of devstack. Everything works fine, only when I want to exit the menu I get this error:

```
./script.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token ')'
./script.sh line 12: '2) exit'
```

Here is the `./script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
clear 

echo "================="

echo "test"

echo  "================="

echo "1. test"

echo "2. exit menu"

echo -e "Maak een selectie en druk daarna op <Enter>"

read answer  

case "$answer" in

1) ./installatiedev.sh
2) exit 
esac
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: where is the `;;` in the case? see http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes that was the problem, stupid mistake. The incident has been solved now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Terminate the case conditions 1) and 2) with two semicolon characters ( `;;` ). When a match is found all of the associated statements until the double semicolon are executed.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear 
echo "================="
echo "test"
echo  "================="
echo "1. test"
echo "2. exit menu"
echo -e "Make a selection and then press <Enter> "
read answer  
case "$answer" in
1) ./installatiedev.sh
   ;;
2) exit 
   ;;
esac
```